# Iteration over binarized image with numpy is slow

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy

I need to iterate over all the pixels in a binarized image to find shapes. But it takes a long  time to iterate each image pixel in this manner. Is there any other way to iterate the image pixels in a faster manner ?

```
dimension = im.shape
rows = dimension[0]
cols = dimension[1]
for i in range(0,rows):
    for j in range(0,cols):
        doSomeOperation(im[i,j])
```

Comment: Python loops over Numpy arrays is very slow, since you're looping in Python. You should vectorize your function.

Comment: @rubik i am pretty new to python.. Can you tell me what you meant by vectorizing it ? How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, what your `doSomeOperation` does defines how much it can be speeded-up.

If the mentioned interest in finding shapes actually means finding connected components, then a simple way to speed-up the solution is to use [ndimage.label](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html#scipy.ndimage.measurements.label) followed by [ndimage.find_objects](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.find_objects.html#scipy.ndimage.measurements.find_objects) from the `scipy` package.

Answer (score 1):

As rubik's comment said, python loops are slow in comparison to the speed with which vectorised functions can work. With a vectorised function you define a function that works on a single element (sometimes more if you get into more complicated vectorised functions) and returns a single value. Common vectorised functions are already define like addition and multiplication.

eg.

```
arr = numpy.arange(10)
arr = arr * numpy.arange(10, 20) 
# times all elements arr by the respective element in other array 
arr = arr + 1 
# add 1 to all elements

@numpy.vectorize
def threshold(element):
    if element < 20:
        return 0
    else:
        return element

# @ notation is the same as 
# threshold = numpy.vectorize(threshold)

arr = threshold(arr)
# sets all elements less than 20 to 0
```

However, because you're trying to find shapes, it might be worth saying what areas of pixels you are looking at. So there might be better ways of trying to find what you're looking for.